# Сервер с JSON API. Как сделать правильно и безопасно.

Tags: json, безопасность, шифрование

Я хочу сделать сервер, который будет отдавать данные в формате JSON. (Как например у [Github.com](http://developer.github.com/)).

Но проблема в том, что мне необходимо защитить передаваемые данные от перехвата. Кроме того доступ к некоторым возможностям будет выборочным. (Т.е. нужна аутентификация и авторизация).

Как это сделать? Можно использовать любые технологии, но желательно не слишком маргинальные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Авторизация по сложным паролям-токенам (средствами вашего кода) + HTTPS средствами apache+mod_ssl.

Естественно, если клиент - браузер рядового пользователя - потребуется валидный сертификат.

Если же использовать нешифрованный протокол - то можно пытаться защитить авторизацию через хеш на клиенте и рендомную "соль".

Опять таки - все зависит от клиента. Если это браузер - решение должно быть максимально стандартным. 
Если коммутация сервер-сервер - тогда что угодно, вплоть до v3 SSL auth(обмен сертификатами).